# Error in File CrystalReportfile.rpt: Failed to load database information

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, crystal-reports

crystal report is displaying in development level but is not displaying at production level. we are using  oracle DB. This is asp.net web app. please help us. Thanks in Advance

```
ReportDocument reportdocument = new ReportDocument();
reportdocument.Load("D:\\CrystalReport1.rpt");
reportdocument.SetDatabaseLogon("username", "password", "ds", "");
reportdocument.SetParameterValue("vseason", txtSeason.Text);
reportdocument.SetParameterValue("slipNo", txtSlip.Text);
CrystalReportViewer2.ReportSource = reportdocument;
```

at production level we are getting this error.
Error in File CrystalReportfile.rpt: Failed to load database information.